how to calculate the tick from price ? Uniswap v3

This is USDC/ETH pool with 0.05% poolfee. I am planning to get the price range from users (lower price and higher price ) but if the user provide lower price as 0.00025991932 and higher price is 0.00033985099 then how can I calculate the lower tick and uppper tick from the prices provided by the user (lower price and higher price).I mean how to calculate lower tick and uppper tick from the low price and high price?
If anyone knows please help
